# IntelliJ 12 not working correctly with JDK 1.7

Tags: compiler-construction, intellij-idea, java, java-7

When I try to run my project (Shift+F10/play button) in IntelliJ 12 Ultimate using *JDK 7 update 7*, I get the following error:

**Java:System Java Compiler was not found in classpath**

I tried:

- manually add my *JDK\bin* path to the path environment variable in Windows, rebooting. (Still didn't help. I got the same error)
- added JDK7u7 under every part of *Project Structure* where one could select a JDK.

However, when I change from JDK7u7 to JDK6u27 then all of a sudden my project compiles *without problems*.

How do I run my project with JDK7?

OS: Windows 7 x64 
Java versions: JDK 1.7u7 i586 32 bit, JDK 6u27 i586 32 bit

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you disable external builds? (`Settings` > `Compiler` > `Use external build`)
Also, do you have a `JAVA_HOME` variable which points to a **JDK** and not a **JRE**?

Comment: Does my JAVA_HOME have to point to a JDK?

Comment: [It seems so](http://jasonshultz.com/blog/2012/11/29/fix-java_home-and-intellij-ideas-broken-jdk), in case you don't have any `JDK_HOME` set.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with JDK 6 + Android 18, which I haven't touched in ages.  It actually broke just while intellij was running.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used IntelliJ, but invalidating caches ( FILE -> invalidate Cache) often helps with different kind of these problems.

Moreover I would recommend installing the latest Java7 JDK Version because of some security issues lately.

Comment: Invalidate Caches didn't help. I will try to install the latest JDK7 then.